# fill individual combobox in gridview combocolumn from another event

Tags: c#, gridview, window

I have create two Combobox column in gridview. Now i want to fill second combobox depending on value of first combobox (On first combobox selectedValueChanged event). Please reply.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Did you tried anything so far? Please show your effort first.. Read [FAQ] and [ask] also..

Answer (score 0):

General approach may look like this:

```
private MyType1 _selectedItem1;
public MyType1 SelectedItem1
{
    get { return _selectedItem1; }
    set 
    {
        if (_selectedItem1 == value) return;
        _selectedItem1 = value;
        //replace with string implementation, if needed
        OnPropertyChanged(() => SelectedItem1);
        if (_selectedItem1 == ...)
        {
            ItemsSource2 = new List<MyClass2> { ... };
        }
        else if (_selectedItem1 == ...)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}

private IList<MyType2> _itemsSource2;
public IList<MyType2> ItemsSource2
{
    get { return _itemsSource2; }
    set 
    {
        if (_itemsSource2 == value) return;
        _itemsSource2 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(() => ItemsSource2);
    }
}
```